# Ajax not loading data from ckeditor

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ckeditor

i am working on ajax with php, try to get data from ckeditor but not working
this is my codes

```
 <form>     
<textarea id="editor" name="Content" required></textarea> 
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn-answer"  class="dislike">Answer</button>
</form>
```

Ajax.js

```
  $("#btn-answer").click(() =>
  {
    var message = $("#editor").val(); 
 
  

      $.ajax({
        type: "post", 
        url: "data/answer.php", 
        data: {  
          'Content':message
         
         },
         beforeSend:function(){
              $(".loader").show();
         },
        success: function(data){
         $("#msg").html(data);
         $(".loader").hide();
        },
      });
    
   
  });
```

answer.php

```
<?php 

$message = $_POST['Content']; 
$status = 1; 

$query = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO answer(userid, answer,topicid,active)VALUES('$Userid','$message','$topicid','$status')"); sleep(3);
if($query){
    echo "<div class='alert alert-dismissible fade show alert-info' role='alert'>You have the questions successfully !</div>";
}else{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-dismissible fade show alert-danger' role='alert'>Something Went Wrong Please Try Again !</div>";   
}



?>
```

this is the ckeditor[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJeQ8.png)
and once the button is clicked, it show blank page with 2022
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wK9Bx.png)
i need help please

Comment: ckeditor has its own function to get value. You can get it using: 
`var desc = CKEDITOR.instances.editor.getData();`

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use this code in production, but on a local server to larn or test something..

1. use the console to see if the **message** variable is not empty; console.log(message);
2. use error_reporting(E_ALL); to see the errors,
3. check if $Userid and $topicid are defined,
4. check the last record with mysqli_insert_id() and the $query variable to see what it returns.